# Decimal value is not recognized by F# console

Tags: f#, decimal

I'm practicing F# for the first time and I thought I'd try to make a program that would calculate the areas of different kinds of shapes. However, the portion that finds the area of a circle is giving me a lot of trouble.`enter code here`

```
elif stringInput = "2" then
let PI = 3.14156
printfn "What is the circle's radius: "
let radiusString = System.Console.ReadLine()
let radiusInt = radiusString |> float
let cirlceArea = (radiusInt * radiusInt) * PI

printfn "The area of the circle is : %d" cirlceArea
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the radiusString |> float part of the code, but nothing I've tried works and I've had no luck in finding any examples that can help. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I just found out the problem was that I was using %d instead of %f